# How can the contents of a TeX \mark be viewed?

Tags: header-footer, tex-core

The purpose of marks in TeX is to generate running heads. One inserts material to a mark, simply by:

```
  \mark{A running head}
```

If we write a short TeX program, we can see that the contents of `\mark` are not available to the `\meaning` or `\show` commands (they are displayed as `\mark`).

```
\mark{A running head}
\tt
\meaning\mark
\show\mark
\show\mark
\bye
```

How can one view the contents of a `\mark`?

Comment: Doesn't that mean that it is a TeX primitive so that it is not decomposable into simpler functions?

Comment: @PeterGrill Since one is adding user content, I am sure there is a probably a devious way of finding what it holds.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Yes, but there must be some formal definition of it. I'm thinking this lies in the [TeX Program](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

only really makes sense to look in the output routine, but....

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\mark{aaa}
\toks0\expandafter{\botmark}\showthe\toks0

aaa

\clearpage

\toks0\expandafter{\botmark}\showthe\toks0

\end{document}
```

shows aaa on the page after the mark

Comment: that was quick:-)

Comment: With e-TeX, you could use `\showtokens\expandafter{\botmark}` rather than the toks here.

Comment: Ah, yes. I must get my TeX usage into this millennium one of these days.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --Thanks that was quick, indeed:)

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks also for your comment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\showtokens` is not exactly the most crucial part of e-TeX! (It's handy, though, as it makes things that little bit clearer.) I guess I'm very used to e-TeX, as I'm always looking over old code and thinking 'can e-TeX help here' :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The `\mark` command just adds material to the vertical list; in the output routine, you have access to various marks via `\topmark` (latest mark on the previous page), `\firstmark` (first mark on the present page), and `\botmark` (last mark on the present page).

I suppose you can examine marks by writing a special output routine, triggering it out of turn, examine the expansions of the above control sequences, and have the special output routine put everything back without doing any output. I am not at all sure why you would want to do such a thing, though.

Comment: Harald -- Thanks. I am trying to manipulate the contents of a vbox, which has a height of `\textheight`, then split it do some manipulation etc, if possible before the contents reach the output routine, my understanding is that I maybe able to see the contents via splittopmark, splitbotmark, however I haven't managed to achieve it, hence the question.